# Crop a range of images to the same size

Tags: graphics, gimp, crop, paint.net

I have a series of images I would like to crop by having a 'cropping rectangle' of fixed size, that I can position slightly differently on each image to be cropped. If I resized them, they would all resize from the same vantage, where I want to trim different parts of different images, and have them all come out the same size.

Comment: You list GIMP and Paint.net.  Are you using a specific program and are looking for a procedure, or are you asking for a recommendation of a program that can help you do this (which would be off-topic on Super User)?

Comment: I'm asking primarily how to do it in Paint.NET, but an alternate procedure, which I suspect will not be too different, in Gimp, would be really useful as well. I have and use both, but Gimp very infrequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixed Size Cropping

I'd love to automate this using `imagemagick` (or similar) and scripting; but it sounds like you want to manually position the crops, so here we go with `GIMP`:

**1)** The selection tool (`r`) has a *Fixed* mode, for choosing a specific aspect ratio, width, height, or **size**. The last is what you are looking for.

**2)** Having chosen your size, *click* on your image and *drag* to position the box as desired.

**3)** Crop by going to `Image -> Crop to selection`, or quicker since you will be doing several images, `alt+i -> c`.

**4)** Done and save!

[image]

*(Mandelbrot fractal thanks to `Filters -> Render -> Fractal Explorer`)*

Happy cropping!

Comment: seems like these days there's a fixed size mode directly in the crop tool.